# How to check for duplicate records before inserting them to DB(2 Primary Keys)

Tags: c#, sql, database, duplicates

I am having a problem with checking 2 values in my database at the same time at the same row, in my table i have 2 primary keys (`Date` and `TagNumber`), and before I am inserting any new data i want to check for duplicate records.

I need to check I am not inserting any new data with the same `date` and the same `tagnumber`.

For example: Current Record

```
Date: 25/03/2015 
TagNumber:111
```

When new data is available I need to check that the `Date` and the `TagNumber` do not already exist on another record (as this would be a duplicate).

So if the new data is

```
Date:25/03/2015
TagNumber:111
```

This record would already exist and would skip inserting a new record. However if the new data was:

```
Date:27/03/2015 
TagNumber:111
```

This would be a new record and would proceed to insert to data.

Code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {

            string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\koni\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\t\Project\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from ResultsTable where TagNumber=@TagNumber AND Date=@Date", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    string smdt1 = row.Cells["Exposure Date"].Value.ToString();
                    string format1 = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(smdt1, format1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dt1);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagNumber", row.Cells["Device #"].Value);

                }
            }
        }
```

and i have tried already `ExecuteScalar()` command and its not good - it worked only on 1 parameter....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, its not really clear whats in this table or your data types. Lets assume your data types are `TagNumber: int` and `Date: datetime`.

Next your problem is probably with the date field.

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(smdt1, format1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

Will parse the date as you would expect. However this will also return the time. So in your query the param `@Date` will also add the time portion automatically to the result (place a breakpoint and have a look). Now as you supplied `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` the time is set to `00:00:00` UTC time which will be translated to the current timezone. (Being here in Australia puts that to 10:30:00).

`sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dt1.Date); //parsed date at midnight 00:00:00`

Now IMHO using a stored procedure would be your best bet as you can use a single query to query and insert.

A sample procedure such as.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNewRecord
    @TagNumber int,
    @Date datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ResultsTable WHERE [Date] = @Date AND TagNumber = @TagNumber)
        INSERT INTO ResultsTable (TagNumber, [Date]) VALUES (@TagNumber, @Date)
END
GO
```

Next you can easily call this (note just using test data).

```
var tagNumber = "111";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("28.01.2017", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC InsertNewRecord @TagNumber, @Date", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagNumber", tagNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date.Date);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

As you see from the stored procedure we are simply querying first (using the `NOT EXISTS` and selecting a true result limiting to a single row for performance. `SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ..` returns a single row of 1 if both the tag number and date exist on a record.

Now you could also change your data type from `datetime` to `date` which eliminates the `time` portion of your `@Date` paramater. However this will require you to ensure your data is clean and the table would have to be rebuilt.

One final option is to cast your `datetime` fields to a `date` in your query and change the `@Date` paramter to a type of `date` then check if they are equal such as.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE InsertNewRecord
    @TagNumber int,
    @Date date
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ResultsTable WHERE cast([Date] as date) = @Date AND TagNumber = @TagNumber)
        INSERT INTO ResultsTable (TagNumber, [Date]) VALUES (@TagNumber, @Date)
END
GO
```

For completness if for some reason you dont want to use a Stored Procedure the following will check if the record exists (note using the `.Date` property).

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    bool exists = false;
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ResultsTable WHERE TagNumber=@TagNumber AND [Date]=@Date", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagNumber", tagNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date.Date);

        con.Open();
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //returns object null if it doesnt exist
        con.Close();

        exists = result != null; //result will be one or null.
    }
    if (exists)
    {
        //INSERT RECORD
    }
}
```

Either way I would say the issue is lying on the time portion of the data however without more information we can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done on the SQL side. Pass your parameters to a stored proc that checks if a record already exists in the table and if so, either returns an error or discards the record. If it doesn't exist, insert it into the table. You can't do it on the client side as you wouldn't have the full table in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nico explained, creating a stored procedure is better way of doing it.